# Problem getting picture in document

Tags: graphics, pdftex, logos

I am a LaTeX rookie and would like some help!

Have problem with not getting a picture/logo in the document.

I am using `TexWorks` on Mac OSX with `pdfLaTeX` as compiler.

Here is my code. The pic is is the same directory as the .tex file.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, draft]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{logga.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have tried a lot of things but never got it to work..

I am thankful for all the answers!